# URL Decode Difference between C# and Java

Tags: java, decode

I got a url encode string %B9q

while I use C# code:

```
string res = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%B9q", Encoding.GetEncoding("Big5"));
```

It outputs as 電，which is the correct answer that I want

But when I use Java decode function:

```
String res = URLDecoder.decode("%B9q", "Big5");
```

Then I got the output ?q

Does anyone knows how it happens and how should I solve it?

Thanks for any suggestions and helps!

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue or not, but according to the JavaDoc for URLDecoder, `It is assumed that all characters in the encoded string are one of the following: "a" through "z", "A" through "Z", "0" through "9", and "-", "_", ".", and "*".` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Comment: Doesn't Big5 always require at least 2 bytes (unless it is an ascii character)? If I understand that correctly, then %B9q does not seem likely to be a valid url encoding. In any case, I do not believe there is any way it can represent anything other than %B9 (decoded as a single code point) + q, which is what java is doing.

Comment: @Mike K, that is because the encoded values are in hex.

Comment: According to this page, that character (電) should be encoded in Big5 as `%B9%71`   http://ash.jp/code/cn/big5tbl.htm

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the [relevant spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#page-14), it looks like Java's way of handling things is correct.

Especially the example presented when discussing URI to IRI conversion seems meaningful:

> Conversions from URIs to IRIs MUST NOT use any character encoding
> other than UTF-8 in steps 3 and 4, even if it might be possible to
> guess from the context that another character encoding than UTF-8 was
> used in the URI.  For example, the URI
> "http://www.example.org/r%E9sum%E9.html" might with some guessing be
> interpreted to contain two e-acute characters encoded as iso-8859-1.
> It must not be converted to an IRI containing these e-acute
> characters.  Otherwise, in the future the IRI will be mapped to
> "http://www.example.org/r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9.html", which is a different
> URI from "http://www.example.org/r%E9sum%E9.html".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Java's URLDecoder ignore some rules on big5 encoding standard. C# do same things as browsers like Chrome, but Java's URLDecoder doesn't. See the relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27635806/1321255